# libgdx Anti-Aliasing, textures

Tags: android, libgdx

Im trying to draw simple (really high resolution: 3333x5829, around 3 times bigger than the desktop launchers width and height) texture to the entire screen. The problem is lines are so badly rendered in desktop launcher. Is there any solution to fix it for the desktop launcher? Here is the render function and the outputs on phone(right) and desktop(left). I shrinked the images to fit the screen, the difference is far more obvious when it's bigger:

```
 @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(texture, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        batch.end();
    }
```

[image][image]

Comment: Use mip mapping. But it seems wasteful to load a texture bigger than the screen.